# Why does orientation change animate when UIView is hidden?

Tags: iphone, uikit

My UIView is hidden, however when the device orientation changes i still see the orientation-change animated black clipping areas. How do i prevent this?

Comment: You could always tell it to stop adjusting to the orientation of the iOS device

Comment: No, i need orientation changes, i just don't want the animation to show when the view is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of the window to your application background color.  Can help in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Make the view transparent

```
someView.alpha = 0.0f;
```